# Python nested loop with two outputs in a single-line

Tags: python, nested-loops

Is it possible to create a python nested loop that returns two array entries for each cycle of the loop?

For example I can have this output from this nested loop:

```
>>> [x for x in [1,2,3,4,5,6]]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

How can I create a single-line nested loop that would return me something like (the array for loop should stay like [1,2,3,4,5,6]):

```
[99, 1, 99, 2, 99, 3, 99, 4, 99, 5, 99, 6]
```

Where for each cycle inside the loop I would also inject an extra value. Is this possible or my only solution would be to expand this nested loop into a normal loop with two appends?

I want to avoid having this:

```
myArray = []
for x in [1,2,3,4,5,6]:
    myArray.append(99)
    myArray.append(x)
```

Comment: Just to clarify: the name of this syntax is "list comprehension" - the counterpart without surrounding `[]` which will generate the values lazily is called "generator expression", and the similar syntaxes for dicts and sets are called "dict comprehension" and "set comprehension".  The expression "nested loop" itself refers to no formal construct, but it is what is _needed_ in order to achieve what you want here: a nested loop inside a comprehension.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible, but unfolding it in 3 lines might be more readable, and therefore a better option than a list comprehension:

You have to use:

- one way to repeatedly generate the constant value you want to interleave. - this can be done with `itertools.repeat`;
- pack both values together for each iteration: the builtin `zip` does that;
- iterate  the packed values: the one coming from your normal source and the one injected: you need another `for` statement. I find it a bit counterintuitive that in comprehensions, nested loops are just nested as in normal code, but the expression making use of the loop values (`v`) in this case, is in the outermost part, as a prefix:

```
from itertools import repeat

result = [v for bundle in zip(repeat(99), [1,2,3,4,5]) for v in bundle]
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're open to defining the list in a separate line then you could loop over a range `2*len(last)` and select either an item from the list (when your iteration counter is odd) or the number 99 (when it's even).

```
lst = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
[lst[x//2] if x%2 else 99 for x in range(2*len(lst))]
```

Which gives

```
[99, 1, 99, 2, 99, 3, 99, 4, 99, 5, 99, 6]
```